# Returning reference contained in an input wrapper type using AsRef

Tags: generics, rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a wrapper around a `&str` to maintain an invariant. When I try to return a new wrapper that basically wraps the same data wrapped by the argument to a function
([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c2ca5f7ffdaa245e7857d8d6d80f0d79)), I'm getting "cannot return value referencing function parameter `s`"

```
struct MyStrWrapper<'a> {
    raw: &'a str,
}

impl AsRef<str> for MyStrWrapper<'_> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        &self.raw
    }
}

fn my_function<'inp>(s: MyStrWrapper<'inp>) -> MyStrWrapper<'inp> {
    MyStrWrapper {
        raw: &s.as_ref()[1..],
    }
}
```

The indexing is unrelated to the error, but it works when I directly access the member with `s.raw` instead of via `as_ref()`. Is there a good way around this that doesn't make `raw` visible to `my_function`?

Comment: In this case you can't use `AsRef`, as `my_function` consumes `s`, and the lifetime of what's returned by `as_ref()` only lives during the `my_function` call. So when `s` is dropped, that invalidates what `as_ref()` returned. If you instead borrow `s`, i.e. `s: &'imp MyStrWrapper<'imp>`, then your code will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass `s` as a reference with the same lifetime ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b4ed63d33153551cf42a9d037988340)):

```
fn my_function<'inp>(s: &'inp MyStrWrapper<'inp>) -> MyStrWrapper<'inp>
```

And then call with reference:

```
my_function(&s);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the main requirement is not making the inner `raw` field visible to `my_function` and you're okay with consuming the original `MyStrWrapper` instance before wrapping the inner `&str` in a new instance then I would suggest using the `From` trait to convert between `MyStrWrapper` and `&str` and use that within your implementation of `my_function`. Example:

```rust
struct MyStrWrapper<'a> {
    raw: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> From<MyStrWrapper<'a>> for &'a str {
    fn from(item: MyStrWrapper<'a>) -> Self {
        item.raw
    }
}

fn my_function<'inp>(s: MyStrWrapper<'inp>) -> MyStrWrapper<'inp> {
    // convert MyStrWrapper into &str without exposing "raw" field to function
    let inner_str = s.into();
    // do whatever you need to do with inner_str here
    // re-wrap inner_str here
    MyStrWrapper {
        raw: inner_str,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStrWrapper {
        raw: "Hello, world!",
    };
    my_function(s);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0b825e3fd8976d8e1e3ad90333e14d32)

---

If you really want to hide `raw` from `my_function` you can also implement the conversion in the other direction, `&str` to `MyStrWrapper` using the `TryFrom` trait since it's possible for the conversion to fail if the invariant isn't met. Updated example:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

struct MyStrWrapper<'a> {
    raw: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> From<MyStrWrapper<'a>> for &'a str {
    fn from(item: MyStrWrapper<'a>) -> Self {
        item.raw
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyInvariant {
    FailureReason
}

impl<'a> TryFrom<&'a str> for MyStrWrapper<'a> {
    type Error = MyInvariant;

    fn try_from(item: &'a str) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        // check invariant on item
        // if fails return Err(MyInvariant::FailureReason)
        // else
        Ok(MyStrWrapper {
            raw: item
        })
    }
}

fn my_function<'inp>(s: MyStrWrapper<'inp>) -> MyStrWrapper<'inp> {
    // convert MyStrWrapper into &str without exposing "raw" field to function
    let inner_str: &str = s.into();
    // do whatever you need to do with inner_str here
    // re-wrap inner_str here
    inner_str.try_into().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStrWrapper {
        raw: "Hello, world!",
    };
    my_function(s);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d1b7282f4147d5453f503b5953499a89)